# Delete cookies in site information

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cookies

I'm building a web app using Angular. I want to delete cookies, which is shown in site information

[image]

[image]

**But these cookies are not showing in the developer console**

[image]

I want to delete these cookies using JavaScript. But I can't even access these cookies using `document.cookie`. How do I delete these cookies using JavaScript? Any solutions? Feel free to use Jquery or npm package.

Comment: You want to delete cookies set by the spotify.com domain…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying, removing cookies, might not be possible to do directly from the browser via JavaScript.

I cannot confirm from your pictures, but from your problem I deduce that the cookies that are not showing on the developer console or on `document.cookie` have the flag **HttpOnly** this attribute prevents the access to this cookies via JS, from MDN:

> Use the HttpOnly attribute to prevent access to cookie values via JavaScript.

You can find more information about the topic and cookies in general in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#security).